# Why does my inputchar function keep looping?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char item;
    Node *next; 
};

void inputChar ( Node * );
void printList (Node *);
char c;

int main()
{

    Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    c = getchar();
    if ( c != '.' )
    {
        head = new Node;
        head->item = c;
        inputChar(head);
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}

void inputChar(Node *p)
{
    getchar();
    while ( c != '.' )
    {
        p->next = new Node;             
        p->next->item = c;
        inputChar(p->next);
    } 
    p->next = new Node; // dot signals end of list              
    p->next->item = c;
}

void printList(Node *p)
{
    if(p = NULL)
        cout << "empty" <<endl;
    else
    {
        while (p->item != '.')
        {
            cout << p->item << endl;
            printList(p->next);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a linked list of characters that are input by the user.  A period indicates the end of the input.  My program keeps looping on the inputChar function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok adding the c = getchar() stopped the looping.

Comment: I think you need to learn about global variables, and why they are a bad idea.

Comment: Good catch.  I changed the while's to if's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should add:

```
c = getchar();
```

Still, it's kind of dangerous what you are doing. In some platforms, `getchar()` will return immediately after consuming the ENTER key of the previous `getchar()` call. So you should consider that in your loop. Perhaps adding an extra `getchar()` to the inputChar function?

Also, what Paul wrote is true. You should change your `while` loop with a simple `if`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you never change the value of `c` inside the loop.  So why would it ever break out?

You only set the value of `c` once before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have inputChar calling inputChar.  When you get X deep into the inputChars and one gets the ., when it returns, its caller still has c equal to whatever it was before it called inputChar, so it continues to loop.

Comment: True. Didn't realize that. Perhaps he should change his while loop with a simple if...

Comment: No, I think he should change the whole logic to avoid all the recursive calls.  They aren't necessary.

Comment: How can I rework this problem without recursion?  I'm not sure how to use iteration with pointers to create a linked list.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify change getchar(); to c = getchar(); on the first line of the inputChar procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this, which tests for both a premature end and the designated end-of-line delimiter, and will allow you to specify a different stream than std::cin in the future.

```
void inputChar(Node *p, std::istream& in = std::cin)
{
    char ch;
    while(in.get(ch) && in && ch != '.')
    {
       ...
    } 
}
```